# Save File and close Jmeter GUI with command line

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, load

I am currently trying to automatically record a JMeter script using Selenium. Therefore i start Jmeter in GUI-Mode through Jenkins (using a batch file) with activated Script Recorder.

Then i run a Selenium-test also through Jenkins and a batch file. The requests that this Selenioum script is doing are successfully being recorded.

The only step that i was not able to figure out yet is to save the recorded JMX-Script and close JMeter.

Is there a way to do this through command line, batch file or other? Doing it manually is not an option since JMeter is running on a remote node through Jenkins.

I was able to close JMeter through a system exit/kill command but this way the jmx-file is not being saved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible as of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html), you will need to automate JMeter GUI separately using [Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) or [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/) or [ldtp](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

However I believe it will make more sense to reconsider your approach and go for one of the following options:

1. Replay your Selenium test using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as the [proxy](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/)
2. Use [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) which has [Proxy2JMX Converter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/)
3. If above 2 options for some reason cannot be used in your environment you can automate i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) from Selenium (check out [6 Easy Steps to Testing Your Chrome Extension With Selenium](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium/) for details) so you will be able to start the recording and export resulting .jmx script directly from your browser without having to communicate with the remote Jenkins/JMeter instances.